# Building an R package

Tags: r, package

I am currently building an R package.

I wish to provide example data. I am aware of the data directory created by package.skeleton() and how to load datasets, etc.

The problem is, I designed the functions to read files as input - the reason being that those using my package will typically be loading large datasets. As such, my functions read files line by line.

I am having an issue getting my package to pass the check stage as I am unclear how to get my functions to read the sample data files as opposed to first loading them and then passing the resulting table/data frame as an argument.

I hope this is clear.

Thanks in advance!

#### Edit ### Response to comment

My function takes a file as argument, i.e.,

```
example <- function(test_file){

test <- readLines(testFile)

....Do something to each line ...

}
```

I am unclear how to pass a file as opposed to a dataframe to my function with my R documentation code.

My test code in the documentation is like below

```
\examples{
library(new_package)
tester <- test(testfile=somefile)
}
```

This fails to execute as it appears R is expecting a data structure like:

```
data(somedataset)
testet <- example(somedataset)
```

The error results from the R CMD check process not being able to locate and read my files. Is there a way that I can construct my package so that the arguments for functions are files and not data structures and if so, how do I pass this files as arguments in my example code in the documentation.

Comment: Can you tell us the exact errors you are seeing during the `check()`?

Comment: How about adding a `\dontrun{` to the examples? That would allow you to pass the check.

Comment: Do you really have a function named `example`?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you are doing things to this file line by line. Seems super inefficient and slow in R.

Comment: Do you have example files in your package such that you could use `system.file(..., package='new_package')`?  Also, please add to your question the error message you are getting.

Comment: @GSee - no - example is as it says - an example! Maiasura - I completely agree but users of this function (including myself) will typically be analysing massive high-throughput biological datasets. Reading into memory will simply not be possible on standard desktop machines.

Comment: I was just asking to see if you were trying to mask the `utils::example` function.  You should look at the help for that function (`?example`) to see what Maiasaura is talking about re: `\dontrun{}`

Comment: you can read things by _chunks_ of manageable size (but better than one line at a time), and there are packages to facilitate this.

Answer (score 1):

What about this example function:

```
#' Example function
#' @param test_file file path
#' @examples \dontrun{
#' example(system.file('example_data.txt', package='package_name'))
#' }
example <- function(test_file) {
    test <- readLines(testFile)
    # whatever you wish to do
}
```

**In details:**

- moving the example dataset from `data` dir (which is to hold datasets to be loaded without custom functions if I am right) to e.g. `inst` directory, which would end up placing your example file in the installed package's directory,
- referencing the demo file with `system.file` in the docs,
- and specifying the example with `\dontrun` to eliminate any warnings caused by running those automatically but still showing up in the docs (although that latter is not needed IMHO if the above is OK).

Answer (score 0):

I understand your dilemma with big data (I'm a biologist dealing with the same issues) so I would suggest not running the example. That would allow you to pass checks but you should also add a little note (as a comment or elsewhere in the function documentation) indicating why these are not straightforward example to run.

```
\examples{
\dontrun{
# Throw in your examples here
 }
}
```

This should allow you to pass checks (at least get around this issue) and make your package installable.